# How to navigate from one page to another using HTML Menu?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, .net

[image]In my project i am using html menu.I tried this code to navigate

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
    <li><a href="Masters/ConfigurationMapping.aspx">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

While clicking Home menu it shows "The resource cannot be found".I have given Correct URL only.i don't know what error is this.

Comment: probably the file is not in that path

Comment: @Er.SajalTiwari File inside the path only.

Comment: check the spelling. some times we will do typo.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai spelling correct.

Comment: can you the screen shot of your folder hierarchy .

Comment: maybe the location/directory of html or the ConfigurationMapping.aspx are not properly arranged.

Comment: tell me the directory name of your calling pge and callled page

Comment: @AmitKumar I have attached screenshot

Comment: and whats the name of your file where you link the other page?

Comment: "~/Masters/ConfigurationMapping.aspx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://freepages.computers.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~pasher/links.htm) you finde how to navigate in folders with html:

citation of the site

**Some URL Shorthands**

directory structure:

[image]

Directory TreeA relative link can be used to link to any other file at the same URL. If your directory structure looks something like the one at the right, a relative link can be written from index.html to any file in the root directory (genealogy_html), or any of the subdirectories in that directory:

```
a href="aboutme.htm" 
a href="documents/obituaries.html" 
a href="families/brown/surnames.html"
```

Pretty slick, huh? But wait a minute! How do you link from one of those subdirectories back to index.html? You'll have to use an absolute link, right? Not at all. We just use some more HTML magic. It's called dot-dot-slash ( ../ ). Dot-dot-slash tells the browser to move one level back toward the root directory before looking for the path to the file. To link from obituaries.html to index.html, the browser must move up one level from documents to genealogy_html to find the file. The relative link is written like this:

```
a href="../index.html"
```

You can write a relative link from one subdirectory to another. To link from brown/surnames.html to jones/surnames.html, the browser must move back one level to the families directory to find the jones directory:

```
a href="../jones/surnames.html"
```

Need to move back two directory levels? No problem. From "jones/surnames.html" back through families to your home page in genealogy_html:

```
a href="../../index.html"
```

Just add one dot-dot-slash for every directory level you need to move back, until you find the path to the file.

Please look at the site for more informations

**But I think your problem is in your directory and not in your HTML-Code so take a look! ;)**

- Is your .aspx correctly spelled?
- Do you have Synthax-Mistakes in your .aspx file?

UPDATE:

**Probably you must firstly go out one directry:**

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
    <li><a href="../Masters/ConfigurationMapping.aspx">Home</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Working fine..I didn't given "../"into my path.thank u

Answer (score 0):

I think a more elegant way to go about this would be to declare a base URL for all your resources(images, videos, style sheets) in the head tag of your HTML file using base tag element. You could then refer to resources relative to the path defined with base tag.

Comment: it isn't, cause you have to switch this everytime you will change something on your server.... oder switch to an other platform...